# Seeking Elegant or Compact Solution

Tags: combinatorics

Question: How many ways are there to roll a standard die 7 times in a row such that the 5th number shown equals an earlier number?

Is there an elegant way to solve this that does not rely on counting several different cases? My approach so far has been this:

Consider the set of all possible 7-digit sequences consisting of the numbers  $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and subtract all sequences in which the 5th digit is distinct from the first four. This has involved considering all the cases where the first four positions in our sequence are occupied by 1, 2, 3, or 4 distinct digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Count the ways to roll a die seven times so that the fifth roll is different from each of the first four. Whatever the fifth number is, there are $5^4\cdot6^2$ possible choices for the other six numbers, so there are altogether $5^4\cdot6^3$ such ways to roll a die seven times. You want the complement of this, which is $$6^7-5^4\cdot6^3=6^3\left(6^4-5^4\right)\;.$$

Comment: There is some interesting psychology going on here. Because of the order of the dice rolls, the mind automatically locks on to all the ways the first four rolls can go before trying to fit in the fifth. But once you consider the fifth roll first, the solution is blindingly obvious.

Comment: My thoughts, as well. Brian's solution agrees with my own, but mine is not at all so elegant. I was too fixated on the first four rolls.

Comment: @Harald: One could make a case, I think, that an awful lot of elementary combinatorics is about finding the viewpoint that makes the solution fairly clear, if not always quite blindingly obvious!